# Correct way to propagate shouldAutorotate into a deep modal viewcontroller in iOS6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

What is the correct way to propagate `shouldAutorotate` into a deep `modal viewcontroller` in iOS6

Consider the following example:

1. Create a new sample `Tabbed Application` in XCode 4.5
2. In the `Summary`, select **all orientations**
3. Create a new simple `UITabBarController`, e.g. `MyTabBarViewController` and add the code

   ```
   - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
       return YES;
   }

   - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
       return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
   }
   ```
4. In the AppDelegate, replace with `UITabBarController` by `MyTabBarViewController` in order to hook the rotation

   ```
   self.tabBarController = [[MyTabBarViewController alloc] init];
   ```
5. Now the rotation should work, and in the `FirstViewController`, add the code to show a **modal** viewcontroller on click

   ```
   -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

       UIViewController * viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] 
           initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];

       [self presentViewController: [[UINavigationController alloc] 
           initWithRootViewController:viewController2] 
           animated:YES 
           completion:nil];
   }
   ```

**Problem:**

Now since the `SecondViewController` is wrapped by a `UINavigationController`, even I have added `shouldAutorotate` in SecondViewController and can't make the upside down rotation done right.

The only fix is to create a custom `UINavigationController` and also implement `shouldAutorotate` and this should work.

But this approach sound stupid and it require me to fix all UI class by implementing the `shouldAutorotate` and I cannot use shorthands such as `[UINavigationController  alloc] 
                initWithRootViewController...` anymore, I must implement all these `UITabBarController` and `UINavigationController`.

Are there any better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didRotate:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

It's a notification sent by the device which tell the observer about the rotation. Do not forget to removeObserver when you don't need anymore

Answer (score 0):

That is not stupid, and it's seems to be the right way.
You could create a subclass of UINavigationController, and use
`[[MyNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:...]`.